# how to starting Apache and MySQL automatically in UniServer Zero by command line

Tags: windows, command-line, apache-http-server, windows-registry, mysql

i want to start Apache and MySQL automatically by command line in [uniserver zero XIV](https://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/Uniform%20Server%20ZeroXIV/14_0_3_ZeroXIV/)

[here](http://www.uniformserver.com/ZeroXI_documentation/command_line_parameters.html) official site propose that you start it with the following command (And works!):

```
UniController.exe start_both
UniController.exe stop_both
```

It can also be done manually by GUI (And works!):

[image]

**problem:**

curiously the above action modifies the file `C:\UniServerZ\home\us_config\us_config.ini` from `false` to `true`

```
RunAtPcStartUpEnabled=true
RunApacheAtStartUp=true
RunMysqlAtStartUp=true
```

But if I do the modification directly in the file `us_config.ini` (without opening the application), and change these values from `false` to `true`, when I restart the PC, apache + mysql does not start, so the above action must do something else

Also [here](http://www.uniformserver.com/ZeroXI_documentation/run_as_service.html) official site propose to install and run as a service (And it does not work!):

```
C:\UniServerZ\core\apache2\bin\httpd_z.exe -k install -n "us_apache_1"
C:\UniServerZ\core\mysql\bin\bin\mysqld_z.exe --install "us_mysql_1" --defaults-file=C:/UniServerZ/core/mysql/my.ini
C:\UniServerZ\core\apache2\bin\httpd_z.exe -k start -n "us_apache_1"
sc.exe start "us_mysql_1"
```

[image]

but these commands are incomplete and contain source errors

What is the correct way to start with the PC apache + mysql in UniServer Zero XIV (by cmd command line or modifying .ini file)? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved the problem:

**First**: Change `false` to `true` in `\UniServerZ\home\us_config\us_config.ini`

```
RunAtPcStartUpEnabled=true
RunApacheAtStartUp=true
RunMysqlAtStartUp=true
```

**Second**: Open CMD with administrative privileges and run the following commands:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "UniServerRun" /t REG_SZ /F /D "%homedrive%\UniServerZ\UniController.exe pc_win_start"
```

Or on some win x64:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "UniServerRun" /t REG_SZ /F /D "%homedrive%\UniServerZ\UniController.exe pc_win_start"
```

and reboot...

PD: To delete the registry keys:

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "UniServerRun" /F
```

or

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "UniServerRun" /F
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way you can do this with a graphical user interface without using the command line or registry tricks, and that's to setup a **scheduled task**.

1. Open Task Scheduler

   To open Task Scheduler there are multiple methods

   - Windows Key + X then click Computer Management
   - Using the start menu, search for Scheduled Tasks or Computer Management
   - Open Administrative Tools under the Start Menu or Control Panel to find Task Scheduler or Computer Management
2. Click `Create Basic Task` on the Actions menu on the right hand side
   [image: click create basic task in task scheduler]
3. Choose a name for the new activity then click next
   [image: enter a new name for your scheduled task]
4. It’s now time to set the trigger. Choose `When I log on`, and click Next. [image: choose the trigger for your scheduled task]
5. Under Action, choose `Start a program`, and click Next.
   [[image]
6. Click `Browse`
7. Choose the `Unicontroller.exe` file
8. Add the following arguments `start_both`
9. Check the box `Open the Properties dialog for this task when I click Finish` then click finish
   [image: click open the properties dialog when i finish in scheduled tasks]
10. A new window should now open called `Properties for ____(Local Computer)`. On the opened tab, check `Run with highest privileges` then click OK.
    [image: click run with highest privileges in task scheduler]

Comment: good alternative. thanks for your contribution